# Numbering of computable functions

Tags: computability, discrete-mathematics

Is there a numbering (not Gödel numbering) of all computable functions $U(p, x)$, such that the set of numbers of functions defined in zero is exactly the set of even numbers. More formally: $I = \{p,\ |\ U(p, 0)\  \mathrm{defined}\} = 2\mathbb{N}$.

My guess that it's true. But I'm not sure how to prove it.

### Ideas:

We can construct a numbering of all computable functions, defined in zero using the function $F(p, x, t)$ which is equal to $0$ if $U(p, x)$ hasn't finished work in $t$ steps and $1$ in other case. We can do it because set of pairs $(p, t)$ is enumerable.

Then, having this function $V(p, x)$ and some other numbering $U(p, x)$ we can construct numbering

$$
U'(p, x) = 
\begin{cases}
V(\frac{p}{2}, x)\ \ if\ p \vdots 2\\
U(\frac{p + 1}{2}, x)\ \ if\ p \not\vdots 2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Try first constructing such a numbering in which $I = \mathbb{N}$, and use this numbering to solve your question. Give it a few hours.

Comment: What do you mean by "not Gödel numbering"? Any bijection between computable functions and the natural numbers is a Gödel numbering: that's what the term means.

Comment: I meant that this numbering is not the main numbering. (By main numbering i mean such a numbering $U(k, x)$ that for any computable function $V(p, x)$ there exist function $s(p)$ such that $U(s(p), x) = V(p, x)$)

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! You can show such a claim by *giving* the numbering. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some sources use "Gödel numbering" to mean "admissible numbering".

Comment: Ok) Edited my question. Added some ideas.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I think I've constructed a numbering in which $I = \mathbb{N}$, but then I had a problem constructing the numbering I need, because in my construction of $U'(p, x)$ I have only $2\mathbb{N} \subseteq I$ and I don't know how to avoid such case in which for example some odd number $k$ is in $I$ because $U(\frac{k + 1}{2}, x)$ is defined in zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- There are countably many computable functions defined at zero, and countably many computable functions undefined at zero.
- There are countably many natural numbers divisible by 2, and countably many natural numbers not divisible by 2.

Put the two facts together.